# Recursively calling a method inside a class in python

Tags: python, recursion

```
class Example(object):
    def doSomething(self, num):
        if(num < 10 ) : 
            //print the number
        else : 
            //call doSomething() again
```

Here how do I call the `doSomething` method in the `else` condition inside the method?

Comment: `self.doSomething(num-1)`

Answer (score 11):

Call it with `self.doSomething(num-1)`, because `doSomething` would refer to a global function rather than the one in the class. Also put the `print` before the `if` so that it prints the number regardless of what it is (so you can see the numbers decreasing) and put a `return` in it's place:

```
class Example(object):
    def doSomething(self, num):
        print num
        if(num < 10 ) : 
            return
        else : 
            self.doSomething(num-1)
```

---

```
>>> x = Example()
>>> x.doSomething(15)
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
>>>
```